# opening files on non-ANSI systems via old (non wchar) API functions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, internationalization

I'm writing some middleware that's driving me nuts.  I'm looking for some I18N experts to help me out - this is all pretty new to me.

Right now this is all in Windows, but it will have to work on Linux and Mac too, though I bet those will be easy.

I have a system (that I can't touch) that will give me a string that's as a wchar_t*.  It takes input in either UTF-8 or the current locale and does the magic to give me a wchar_t*.

I have another API that I'm using that can only take filenames as char* (That I also can't touch).

So what I've been doing is taking my filename in wchar_t* and using the Windows API function WideCharToMultiByte and converting it to a char* and passing that to my other API function.  It was working just fine until QA decided to use a Japanese OS.  Now the fopen (deep inside the API that I can't touch) is failing.

I've tried using both CP_ACP and CP_UTF8 in my WideCharToMultiByte call and both work on my development (US-English) machine even with Japanese characters in the filename.  But both fail on the Japanese OS.

Any hints on how I should really be handling these filenames?

Comment: Can you record the character data returned at each step, and compare the US-English OS vs the Japanese OS? The first call that gives a different result may indicate which API is causing the trouble.

Comment: Can you try to get information about which locale is active on your target machine? The result string of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` would already be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the correct way to fix this would be to fix the other API. Accepting only narrow, non-unicode filenames is simply broken behavior.

But... you said you can't do that. You might be able to work around this by getting the short file name, which will not have any non ANSI characters, and passing that to the broken API instead. (The reason for this is that short filenames are designed to work for 16 bit applications, and 16 bit windows didn't support Unicode at all)

Of course this will fail if the filename is not representable as a short file name, or if short file names are turned off on the target machine -- but it's really the only option here.

**EDIT**: One more note -- if the filename contains Unicode the short filename will generally not be human readable. It will be renamed to use a bunch of hex garbage which uniquely identifies the file in a world restricted to 8.3 filenames.

Comment: Are you saying that the Standard C++ library is "simply broken"?

Comment: @dan04: The C++ Standard Library defines wide character and narrow character APIs for everything. (And in C++0x, there's even more explicit support for the Unicode transformation formats) Therefore, no, it's not. Large parts of it are broken, yes, but the library as a whole is not. C and C++ really can't be faulted too much here though because they predate Unicode by some 15 years.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  *Windows* defines wide and narrow character APIs for everything.  But Standard C lacks functions like `_wfopen` or `_wstat`.

Comment: @dan: C and C++ are different languages. C++ has `std::wfstream` and friends, which work just fine. Standard C89's library is broken; however, it predates Unicode by about 4 years (and therefore couldn't have ever been right in the first place). C99 fixes most cases by including wide character versions of most of the library (e.g. `wprintf`), with the notable exception of `fopen` (as you already indicated). (I don't see how `_wstat` is involved here given that Standard C does not define a `stat` -- that's a POSIX API)

Comment: @dan: Most of what's broken Unicode-wise for C++ is fixed in C++0x, and there are proposals to fix C's problems for C1X, but both languages really do have serious problems working with Unicode. (C is more excusable here because it's first standard predates Unicode by 4 years, C++ has little excuse because it's first standard postdates Unicode by about 5 years....)

Comment: Yup, I tried all kinds of tricks, but using the short filename is the only way it'll work.  Gah!  I hate Windows.  Mac and Linux were easy - they just use UTF-8.

Comment: Linux are not easy, unless you are lucky. Because it does not use UTF-8, it uses "a bunch of bytes". I can do a LANG=ja_JP.EUC-JP or ru_RU.KOI8-R, create a file with Japanese or Russians characters, change LANG to en_US.utf-8, and left you scratching your head, nothing can save you. At least in Windows you know 100%: FAT32 or NTFS will support UTF-16, you call the Unicode version of the API and you are all set.

Comment: @Miked: I'll take what Windows does over having to transverse UTF-8 strings any day. (Most "UTF-8" code I've seen is hopelessly broken)

Comment: @BillyONeal `std::wfstream` will read wide characters but (in standard C++) it will only take a [`const char*` as filename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/). Besides, the problem is that a lot of libraries only accept a `const char *fileName` and internally call the ANSI version of whatever API used to open that file.

Comment: @BillyONeal Remember UTF-16 (what Windows uses) is also variable length.

Comment: @Roeland: 1. Wow, blast from 2011. 2. I could have swore we fixed that in C++17 but I can't find it now. :/ 3. I never claimed UTF-16 was better. I'm only claiming that UTF-8 is not all unicorns and rainbows.

Comment: @BillyONeal You can't find it because that's an extension on Windows. Follow the link, if it were in C++17 it would have been mentioned on that page.

Comment: @roeland: No, I mean I could have swore I was in the committee meeting where it was added (specifically constructors taking `std::filesystem::path::value_type *`) but I don't see it in the current WP.

Comment: @BillyONeal Ah that's too bad, it would have been a welcome addition. Handling files is a PITA with third-party libraries because of this.

Comment: @roeland: I'm not crazy, it was added, but LWG 2676 isn't merged into the WP yet. http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2676