# Windows usage of char * functions with UTF-16

Tags: c++, windows, encoding

I port one application from Linux to Windows. 
On Linux I use [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) library from which I wouldn't be glad to rid of on Windows.

The problem is that I need pass name of file that is held  in UTF-16 encoding to such function:

`int  magic_load(magic_t cookie, const char *filename);`

Unfortunately it accepts only const char *filename. My first idea was to convert UTF-16 string  to local  encoding, but there are some problems - like string can contain e.g. Chinese symbols and local encoding may be Russian. 
 
 As result we will get trash on the output and program will not reach its aim. 

 Converting into UTF-8 doesn't help either, because this is Windows and Windows holds file name in UTF-16.

But I somehow need make that function able to open file with Unicode name.

I came only to one very very bad solution:

```
 1. I have a filename
 2. I can copy file with unicode name to file with ASCII name like "1.mp3"
 3. open it with libmagic functions and get what I want
 4. remove temporarily file
```

But I understand how this solution is bad and how it could make my application slower, so I wonder, perhaps are there some better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance for any tips, 'cause I'm really confused with it.

Comment: Related or even duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351227/opening-files-on-non-ansi-systems-via-old-non-wchar-api-functions

Comment: It's not clear where you got the Windows version of libmagic from, but you could add a `magic_load_utf16` function that accepts a UTF-16 filename. It would presumably be the same as `magic_load` except that at the end of the day it uses wfopen instead of fopen.

Comment: ah, sorry, I've forgot to notice, I've got it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm and it's for MinGW C++ compiler, unfortunately wfopen is Microsoft Visual C++ specific extension, so my hands are tied

Comment: Perhaps using a symbolic link rather than a copy?

Comment: oh, yea, I started already hoping that it could be a perfect solution. But there appeared one problem -  function for creation  symbolic links (CreateSymbolicLink) is supported only since Windows Vista(but I need  run my up XP too). I wanted to try  CreateHardLink - but  it's supported only on NTFS filesystems (disk may be in  FAT as well). So, I can't use this way too.  P.S. I feel myself already some inconvenient, behaving like a capricious girl who tells only no, no, no. eh, and again I deny proposition, but I can nothing else think up here

Answer (score 5):

Use 8.3 file names to access the files.

In addition to long file names up to 255 characters in length, Windows also generates an MS-DOS-compatible (short) file name in 8.3 format.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982

Comment: Further to that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: oh, it seems that this way is not so reliable, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation      , as I understand unfortunately short names can just not exist

Comment: If the short name doesn't exist, you could fall back to copying the file.